# P4 unshelve file not found error

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-branch-spec

I have a workspace with shelved files. I am trying to unshelve these files into another workspace by using the command :

p4 unshelve -s sourcechangelist -c destinationchangelist

However I am getting "file not found error"

Could anyone tell what I am missing ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please include the **exact** command you issued, and the **exact** output you got, by cutting-and-pasting from the terminal window if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the literal error message "file not found error" it's not coming from Perforce -- I'm guessing you don't have p4 installed on this machine, or you passed an unquoted wildcard that the shell is failing to expand.

If that error message was a paraphrase, most likely there aren't any files shelved in the changelist you passed with "-s sourcechangelist".  Go back to your original workspace and make sure you've shelved the files.